# 404 Errors when trying to access other subdirectories in root with magento serving as primary (Solved)

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I have magento located in a subdirectory in public_html/magento the .htaccess I used to redirect magento to the root is based on [installing Magento in subdirectory](http://husseycoding.blogspot.com/2013/01/installing-magento-in-subdirectory.html)

---

*Root .htaccess file contains*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1
```

The .htaccess in magento only has the change of

*you can put here your magento root folder
path relative to web root*

```
RewriteBase /
```

I would like to be to be able to access other web applications which are located in public_html ie (blog, CMS, forum) without magento throwing a 404 error.

I tried using [Serve main domain from subdirectory with .htaccess](http://yysource.com/2012/11/serve-main-domain-from-subdirectory-with-htaccess/) example but magento still takes over.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Part 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?topdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/topdomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /topdomain/$1
# Part 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?topdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ topdomain/index.php [L]
```

what do I need to put in the root .htaccess to make magento play nicely so
that I can have

```
└── httpd
    ├── blog (topdomain/blog
    ├── cart (topdomain
    ├── forum (topdomain/forum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to have the raw domain link to Magento, but allow other folders in the root domain to work, you can just add a further `RewriteCond` for each top level directory you wish to work.

**root .htacces**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1
```

The `RewriteCond`'s are basically saying if the URL doesn't start with */magento/* and doesn't start with */blog/* and doesn't start with */forums/* then redirect to Magento.

Comment: this solved the problem but do not have enough reputation points to upvote it. Just one more question would I add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$}` to this rule or have to create another rule if a subdomain was included in this?

Comment: If you wish the same redirects to be applied to other domains / sub-domains then yes, you can just add an additional `RewroteCond`.

Comment: ok thank you was getting a little frustrated try to make this work.

Comment: Can be a pain if your not familiar. The important things to remember is that: 1.) The `RewriteCond` directives are associated with the next `RewriteRule`. 2.) By default the rule's are evaluated with AND (they all have to be true). 3.) They are just pattern matches against different variables the server provides.

Comment: So the additional rule for `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$` goes after `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1`

Comment: No,`RewriteCond`s apply to the following `RewriteRule`.